# Regex: Extract substring from beginning up to ' - '

Tags: regex

I can't seem to figure out the JavaScript regex to extract the substring from beginning to a subfix/tag to my strings.  My strings are in these form:

```
3-Hr Workshop - Member
3-Hr Workshop - Guest
1-Hr Workshop - Member
1-Hr Workshop - Guest
Social Only - Member
Social Only - Guest
```

I need to remove the  `- Member` or  `- Guest` from each string so that I end up with:

```
3-Hr Workshop
3-Hr Workshop
1-Hr Workshop
1-Hr Workshop
Social Only
Social Only
```

Is there a way to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### This regex:

```
.*?(?= - (?:Member|Guest))
```

**[Online JS Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6NdUg/1)**

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `-` | ' - ' |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture: |
| `Member` | 'Member' |
| `|` | OR |
| `Guest` | 'Guest' |
| `)` | end of grouping |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: omg, thank you. I came nowhere close to this.

Answer (score 0):

js regex
[image]

```
const str = "3-Hr Workshop - Member";
const regex = /^[^-]*-/;
const result = str.replace(regex, "");

console.log(result); // "3-Hr Workshop"
```

Comment: OP asked to remove `(Member|Guest)`

Comment: Discard... Not remove.